# Screen Flickering Problem 15.10

Tags: virtualbox, 15.10

I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox (latest) and i have a problem with linx ubuntu not really showing the desktop, by this i mean that after i log in and everything, i am greeted with a screen that will blink between showing my windows that i have open and a black background which has what i suspect to be the default Ubuntu background. Before you say use CompizConfig, don't i've already tried with the whole "Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint" workaround, and it hasn't worked. So if you know of a different way to fix this, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for Intel display devices:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update

reboot

sudo apt-get install mesa-vdpau-drivers

wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-3 -O - | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get install gksu

gksudu firefox
```

Open https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0 & download & install the proper version

```
intel-linux-graphics-installer
```